# Omni Channel Setting -MAX 3 Chats & 1 Case

Tags: omnichannel

I am trying to configure omnichannel so an agent can get a mix of chats & cases, but only a max of 3 chats & 1 case.  Struggling to configure to stop at 1 case when no chats presenting & similarly, maximum of 3 chats when no cases to route.

I am sure it will be an obvious answer, but trying all combinations ad unable to meet te brief.

Answer (score 0):

Set the queue to have a Capacity of 3 in the [Routing Configuration Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=service_presence_routing_configuration_settings.htm&type=5) (Setup > Routing Configurations), and [set the agent's Capacity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_managing_capacity_with_service_presence.htm&type=5) to 3 (Setup > Presence Configuration). Chats are worth 1 Capacity, so if the Case is worth 3 Capacity, this would allow the agent to have up to 3 chats or one case at one time.